# Is there a fix for the latest Chrome Dev Tools blunder

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

The latest chrome update changed the console filter from multiple selectable options to a drop down where you can only select one option.  Logs isn't even an option in the menu.  So now there is no way to filter the console to see console.log.

Does anyone know of a way to revert to a previous version of chrome.  What about an extension that will add this functionality back?

Comment: I created a bug ([#717776](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=717776)). One of the engineers will update that bug about whether or not they plan on bringing this back in a later version.

Comment: The change was intentional, and based on the previous history of similar decisions of dumbing down or removing the less frequently used parts of UI, they won't restore the old behavior.

Comment: The developer tools are designed for developers.  Maybe if enough developers complain, they'll change it.  Otherwise they risks loosing a big chunk of their users to another browser.

Comment: There's also a discussion on the [DevTools Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/kH3FiDLlsFg) about this.

Comment: Please Log in and star the bug to let the Chrome developers know how important this is.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=717776#.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue stems from a change made in Chromium.  I've filed a bug with them.  The reason I keep getting back is consistency with other log frameworks.  When I've ask what are the names of those frameworks or were developers even asked if this was a desired change, I get no answer.

Maybe it's time to bombard them with bugs so they'll see this is an unwelcome change by many developers.  Everyone that has replied on this post and all new people coming here, please file a bug concerning this issue at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list .  Through mass bombardment, we'll show them they should check with the users if future change are desired or not.